# I need to find upper bound for $ \frac {1} {| \bar {\beta} z + \bar {\alpha} |}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

$Problem:$ Lets $ | z | < 1$ and $ | \alpha | ^ 2-| \beta | ^ 2 = 1 $, I want to limit $ \frac {1} {| \bar {\beta} z + \bar {\alpha} |}. $ I found an lower bound, but I need to find a upper bound, can anyone give me a suggestion? Thank you.

What I did was:

$$|\bar{\beta}z+\bar{\alpha}|\leq |\bar{\beta}z|+|\bar{\alpha}|<2|\alpha|\;\; \text{as}\;\; |\alpha|>|\beta|$$ then $\frac{1}{2|\alpha|}<\frac{1}{|\bar{\beta}z+\bar{\alpha}|}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inequality $|a-b|\geq |a|-|b|$. We find $|\overline{\beta}z+\alpha|=|\alpha-(-\overline{\beta}z)|\geq |\alpha|-|-\overline{\beta}z|=|\alpha|-|z|\,|\beta|\geq |\alpha|-|\beta|$.

Now, by assumption $(|\alpha|+|\beta|)(|\alpha|-|\beta|)=1$ so 
$$
|\alpha|-|\beta|=\frac{1}{|\alpha|+|\beta|}.
$$
In conclusion, $|\overline{\beta}z+\alpha| \geq \frac{1}{|\alpha|+|\beta|}$ so...

Comment: The value $\frac 1 {|\alpha|+|\beta|}\$ is actually attained so it is the best bound.

Answer (score 1):

$|z|=r,\> r\in[0,1)$ represents a unit disk, which, 
via the Mobius transformation $w=\frac1{\bar{\beta}z+\bar\alpha}$, maps onto a set of circles as

$$| w- c |^2 = R^2$$

with the center $c=\frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|^2-r^2|\beta|^2}$ and the radius $R= \frac{r|\beta|}{|\alpha|^2-r^2|\beta|^2}  $. Then, the upper bound of $|w|$ is the furthest distance on the circle from the origin and the lower bound is the nearest, i.e.

$$ |c|-R\le |w| \le|c|+R$$

which leads to the bounds

$$|\alpha|-|\beta|<\frac1{|\bar{\beta}z+\bar\alpha|}< |\alpha|+|\beta|$$

Note, $|\alpha|-|\beta|$ is the tightest lower bound.